# Unable to update graphs in dash app with the dropdown selectrors

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

Hello I am working on a dash app, and somehow I am not able to update graphs between different divs callback. This is how the app works:

1. The user gives a url input on the frontend in a textinput box and button is clicked to run analysis.
2. The user can select the view mode as well before running the analysis, The view mode depends on the dropdown selector
3. The url is used to display a video frame and run a python function.
4. The processed results should be stored in the dcc.store component.
5. The stored data is then called in to update the graphs.

Below is the callback codes:

```
#Video Selection
@app.callback(Output("video-display", "url"),
              [Input("submit_button", "n_clicks")],
              [State('video_url', 'value')])
def select_footage(n_clicks, video_url):
    if n_clicks is not None and n_clicks > 0:
        url = video_url
        return url


# Processing and Storing the results in dcc.store
@app.callback(Output("intermediate-value", "data"),
              [Input("submit_button", "n_clicks")],
              [State('video_url', 'value')])

def video_processing(n_clicks, value ):
    global frame
    if n_clicks is not None and n_clicks > 0:
        frame = python_func(url)
        return frame.to_json(orient='split')

# Callback to change the graph view mode div
@app.callback(Output("div-graph-mode", "children"),
              [Input("dropdown-graph-view-mode", "value")])
def update_graph_mode(value):
    if value == "graphical":
        return [
            html.Div(
                children=[
                    html.P(children="Retention Score of Detected Labels",
                           className='plot-title'),
                    dcc.Graph(
                        id="bar-score-graph",
                        style={'height': '55vh', 'width': '100%'}
                    ),
                    html.P(children="Audience Retention Behavior",
                           className='plot-title'),
                    dcc.Graph(
                        id="line_chart_retention",
                        style={'height': '45vh', 'width': '100%'}
                    )
                ]
            )
        ]
    else:
        return []

@app.callback(Output("div-table-mode", "children"),
              [Input("dropdown-graph-view-mode", "value")])
def update_table_mode(dropdown_value):
    if dropdown_value == "table":
        return [
            html.Div(
                children=[
                    html.P(children="Retention By Label",
                           className='plot-title'),
                    html.Div([
                        table.DataTable(
                            id="label_retention",
                            )],
                        style={'height': '45vh'}),


                    html.P(children="Retention by Time Stamp",
                           className='plot-title'),
                    html.Div([
                        table.DataTable(
                            id="timestamp_retention",
                            style_table={'maxHeight': '40vh', 'width': '100%', 'overflowY': 'scroll'})],
                        style={'height': '40vh'}
                    )
                ]
            )
        ]
    else:
        return []

# Updating Graphs
@app.callback(Output("label_retention", "figure"),
              [Input("dropdown-graph-view-mode", "value")])
def update_table_bar(value):
    global frame
    if frame is not None:
        print(frame)
        print("table")
        print(value)

@app.callback(Output("bar-score-graph", "figure"),
              [Input("dropdown-graph-view-mode", "value")])
def update_score_bar(value):
    global frame
    if frame is not None:
        print(frame)
        print("graph")
        print(value)
```

Now what happens is that if I try to toggle between the two graph view modes, the app does not reflect the graphs and requires to click on the button again to get the results. So, basically I believe the data does not gets lost in the dcc.store component when I toggle with the dropdowns.

How can I make the app behave in a way that my python function runs only once on the submit button, but then I am able to toggle between the view modes to see the graphs.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

P.S. This is just a snippet of codes, as the code is too long, but please let me know if you would want to see the entire code.

UPDATE: I have just realised that when I select the Graph Mode, the app prints the results for Table Mode and when I select the table model, the app prints the results for graph mode. I am not able to figure out as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve my issue as below:

```
@app.callback(Output("div-table-mode", "children"),
              [Input("dropdown-graph-view-mode", "value")])
def update_table_mode(dropdown_value):
    if dropdown_value == "tabular":
        return [
            html.Div(
                children=[
                    html.P(children="Retention By Label",
                           className='plot-title', style={'margin': '0 0 1em 0'}),
                    html.Div([
                        table.DataTable(
                            id="label_retention",
                            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in label_retention.columns],

                            data=label_retention.to_dict("rows"),

                            style_table={'maxHeight': '40vh', 'width': '100%', 'overflowY': 'scroll'},
                            style_cell_conditional=[
                                {
                                    'if': {'column_id': c},
                                    'textAlign': 'left'
                                } for c in ['Labels']
                            ],
                            style_data_conditional=[
                                {
                                    'if': {'row_index': 'odd'},
                                    'backgroundColor': 'rgb(248, 248, 248)'
                                }
                            ],

                            style_header={
                                'backgroundColor': 'rgb(230, 230, 230)',
                                'fontWeight': 'bold'
                            }
                            )],
                        style={'height': '40vh'}),


                    html.P(children="Retention by Time Stamp",
                           className='plot-title', style={'margin': '1em 0 1em 0'}),
                    html.Div([
                        table.DataTable(
                            id="timestamp_retention",
                            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in timeline_retention.columns],
                            data=timeline_retention.to_dict("rows"),
                            style_table={'maxHeight': '40vh', 'width': '100%', 'overflowY': 'scroll'},
                            style_cell={'textAlign': 'left', 'minWidth': '20px', 'width': '20px', 'maxWidth': '50px',
                                        'whiteSpace': 'normal'},
                            css=[{
                                'selector': '.dash-cell div.dash-cell-value',
                                'rule': 'display: inline; white-space: inherit; overflow: inherit; text-overflow: inherit;'
                            }],
                            style_data_conditional=[
                                {
                                    'if': {'row_index': 'odd'},
                                    'backgroundColor': 'rgb(248, 248, 248)'
                                }
                            ],

                            style_header={
                                'backgroundColor': 'rgb(230, 230, 230)',
                                'fontWeight': 'bold'
                            }
                        )],
                        style={'height': '40vh'}
                    )
                ],
                style={'backgroundColor': '#F2F2F2'}
            )
        ]
    else:
        return []


@app.callback(Output("div-graph-mode", "children"),
              [Input("dropdown-graph-view-mode", "value")])
def update_graph_mode(value):
    if value == "graphical":
        return [
            html.Div(
                children=[
                    html.P(children="Retention Score of Detected Labels",
                           className='plot-title', style={'margin': '0 0 1em 0', 'width': '100%'}),
                    dcc.Graph(
                        id="bar-score-graph",
                        figure=go.Figure({
                            'data': [{'hoverinfo': 'x+text',
                                      'name': 'Detection Scores',
                                      #'text': y_text,
                                      'type': 'bar',
                                      'x': label_retention["Description"],
                                      'marker': {'color': colors},
                                      'y': label_retention["sum"].tolist()}],
                            'layout': {'showlegend': False,
                                       'autosize': False,
                                       'paper_bgcolor': 'rgb(249,249,249)',
                                       'plot_bgcolor': 'rgb(249,249,249)',
                                       'xaxis': {'automargin': True, 'tickangle': -45},
                                       'yaxis': {'automargin': True, 'range': [minval, maxval], 'title': {'text': 'Score'}}}
                        }
                        ),
                        style={'height': '55vh', 'width': '100%'}
                    ),
                    html.P(children="Audience Retention Behavior",
                           className='plot-title', style={'margin': '0 0 1em 0', 'width': '100%'}),
                    dcc.Graph(
                        id="line_chart_retention",
                        figure=go.Figure({
                            'data': [go.Scatter(x=label_retention['Start'], y=label_retention['sum'], mode='lines', name='Audience Retention',
                                                line=dict(color='firebrick', width=4))],
                            'layout': {
                                'yaxis': {'title': {'text': 'Audience Retention'}, 'automargin': True},
                                'xaxis': {'title': {'text': 'Time Segment'}, 'automargin': True},
                                'paper_bgcolor': 'rgb(249,249,249)',
                                'plot_bgcolor': 'rgb(249,249,249)',

                            }
                        }),
                        style={'height': '45vh', 'width': '100%'}
                    )
                ],
                style={'backgroundColor': '#F2F2F2', 'width': '100%'}
            )
        ]
    else:
        return []
```